# Dollar sign breaks syntax highlighting in Vim

Tags: symbols, vim, syntax-highlighting

The `$` symbol opens inline math environment, unless it is used in verbatim enviromnent.

However Vim can’t seem to detect that it’s in a verbatim environment, and as a result the dollar breaks the syntax highlighting, since Vim starts the math mode highlighting until it encounters a new dollar symbol.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Vim fails to detect that the dollar sign is used in a verbatim environment, it probably means it is not using the right syntax highlighting flavour.

Use `:set syntax` to find out which syntax highlighting flavor is used.

The `tex` flavour, meant for LaTeX, should behave correctly.  In addition, it features a `%stopzone` keyword for the cases where it should fail : inserting this keyword in the code will reset the highlighting from where it is placed.

On the other hand, the `plaintex` flavour, meant for TeX, and [used by default when Vim can’t decide which flavour to use](https://superuser.com/a/676732/127425), doesn’t support such subtilities.

To switch to the correct syntax highlighting flavour for this file, use `:set syntax=tex` or add `%&latex` as the first line of the file.

For more permanent solutions, you can add `let g:tex_flavor = "latex"` in your `.vimrc` (not tested).

NB : Note that the dollar sign also breaks the `listings` package environments.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21651323/812102) for a fix and comments therein for its drawbacks.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer says, if you are writing LaTeX you should have `let g:tex_flavor="latex"` set in the `.vimrc.` With that, Vim will skip highlighting `verbatim` environments but it will still not recognize others like `lstlisting` or `minted` (or other custom environments).

After such an environment containing dollar signs, just add the following:

```
%stopzone
```

LaTeX will ignore this, but Vim will take this cue to reset its syntax highlighting.

Vim will still color your included listing in a strange way when there are dollar signs, but it won't have any effect on the outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately `%stopzone` is not supported when Vim considers the file as `plaintex`, see my answer.

Comment: %stopzone must be used without space, otherwise it does not work

Comment: @DmitryMikushin thanks - edited.